# What´s wrong with this MDX query Error: Query (3, 8)?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssas, mdx

I tried to execute this query and i can´t understand what´s wrong with it.

```
 WITH MEMBER Time.T1 AS 'SUM([Time].&[TY].&[0]:[Time].&[TY].&[11])' 
MEMBER Time.T2 AS 'SUM([Time].&[TY].&[0]:[Time].&[TY].&[11])' 
MEMBER Measures.Col1 AS '(Scenario.&[PO], [T1], [GNAm])' 
MEMBER Measures.Col2 AS '(Scenario.&[ACFC], [T2], [GNAm])' 
MEMBER Measures.Diff AS '[Col2] - [Col1]' 
MEMBER Measures.Perc AS 'IIF([Col1] = 0, [Col1], [Diff] / [Col1])', FORMAT_STRING = '#0.00%' 
SELECT {[Col1], [Col2], [Diff], [Perc]} on Columns, Descendants([Account].[Account].[Expenses]) on Rows 
FROM DS_GNA 
WHERE (&[44026-90],&[010000])
```

get error message:

```
Error: Query (3, 8) Parser: The syntax for '&' is incorrect.
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with your WHERE clause?   I suspect that's a definite problem.

Comment: The ampersand (&) character is used in MDX to differentiate a member key from a member name.  Why do you have `[Time].&[TY].&[0]`?  I am assuming TY is an attribute in your Time dimension?  I would expect to see `[Time].[TY].&[0]`.  Start off with one calculated member at a time and make sure it works, then add the next one.  You will figure out what is wrong much more quickly than doing it all at once and hoping for the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the following just repeats the comments to your question. I've totally excluded your `WHERE` clause as best to see if it runs without an exception first. As mentioned by TTeeple I've just included ampersands before key values:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER Time.T1 AS 
    Sum([Time].[TY].&[0] : [Time].[TY].&[11]) 
  MEMBER Time.T2 AS 
    Sum([Time].[TY].&[0] : [Time].[TY].&[11]) 
  MEMBER Measures.Col1 AS 
    (
      Scenario.[PO]
     ,[T1]
     ,[GNAm]
    ) 
  MEMBER Measures.Col2 AS 
    (
      Scenario.[ACFC]
     ,[T2]
     ,[GNAm]
    ) 
  MEMBER Measures.Diff AS 
    [Col2] - [Col1] 
  MEMBER Measures.Perc AS 
    IIF
    (
      [Col1] = 0
     ,[Col1]
     ,
      [Diff] / [Col1]
    ) 
   ,FORMAT_STRING = '#0.00%' 
SELECT 
  {
    [Col1]
   ,[Col2]
   ,[Diff]
   ,[Perc]
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,Descendants([Account].[Account].[Expenses]) ON ROWS
FROM [DS_GNA];
```